# BMP->conversion->PNG->conversion->BMP (PHP function)

Tags: php, laravel, imagick, image-conversion

What is the best way in PHP to convert `bmp` images to png and then to convert back again without losing any information since png is the lossless format?

Both BMP images before and after conversion must be the same size. I have used image intervention but `bmp` image after conversion from png doesn't have the same size as original `bmp`.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want the exact same size / image, you should not convert it? Your question is a little weird: I want A -> B -> A and A has to be the same. Well Don't do the step to B.

Comment: I need to do this for college, because png have smaller size than bmp and if you send it to another user this is better because of its smaller size.

Comment: Then why use BMP at all, and why is it required that the result is *exactly* the same? How big is the difference? Different programs encoding the image may result in differences by subtle differences in how the programs, e.g., write meta data. But the result may still be lossless.

Comment: I have found the  solution. Instead of using Imagick, Php functions imagecreatefrombmp and imagepng (and reverse) works fine!. Both bmp images after conversion to png and back, have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Using php functions **imagepng and imagecreatefrombmp** resolved the problem. But only for 24-bit bitmap images.

Previously I have used image intervention with imagick driver but it didn't worked.